# is there any Objective-C web crawler framework?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, web-crawler

is there any Objective-C web crawler framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time there doesn't seem to be any widely used web spider/crawler Objective C kit or library.

[WebCrawler](http://webcrawler.com/) (which was one of the [first search engines](http://slashdot.org/story/04/04/20/225254/WebCrawler-Turns-10-Today)) was apparently written, at least originally, in Objective C on the NeXT platform.  The author of that system mentioned that he [might release it](http://www.prenhall.com/electronic_publishing/html/chapter1/01_4.html) as open source once, way back when.  You might try contacting him to see if he would be willing to release a basic Objective C web crawler kit.  (He may not be able to do that, as he sold the WebCrawler company years ago.)

There is a shareware library which includes an Objective C spider called [CkoSpider](https://chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/objcCkoSpiderDoc.html) from "Chilkat".

There are quite a few (brief) discussions of this idea around the web (such as this one:  [Can I build a web spider with WebKit?](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/webkit-help/2009-August/000175.html)), with several folk apparently deciding over the years to roll their own.  My guess is that each of them had a relatively simple and specific project need, and never got to the point where they thought they had something of general interest. You might be able to get a critical mass of developer users of such a kit these days, what with all the renewed Objective C interest due to iPad and iPhone.  If you roll your own, consider doing it as a public github project, to see if you can tap into this interest.

Comment: are you interested in working on such project like this ? i would like to create a framework for this matter ! if you are interested we can work together .

Comment: I'm oversubscribed, already.  If you're looking for possible partners, Google around and read the various discussions where other people were looking for something like this, and contact the participants.  You can usually google your way to their email address pretty easily.  Undoubtedly a few of them would still be interested.

Comment: Does anyone succeeded in creating some web-crawler?